# Create SVG elements with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, svg, typescript, tslint

I'm trying to create a properly formatted SVG element in TypeScript:

```
createSVGElement(tag) {
    return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
}
```

However, I get the following error in `tslint`

> Forbidden http url in string: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

How do I avoid this error? I thought I required this URL to meet the SVG standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tslint` is complaining due to the `no-http-string` rule. The rule is defined as:

> Do not use strings that start with 'http:'. URL strings should start with 'https:'. Http strings can be a security problem and indicator that your software may suffer from cookie-stealing attacks. Since version 1.0, this rule takes a list of regular expressions as a parameter. Any string matching that regular expression will be ignored. For example, to allow http connections to example.com and examples.com, configure your rule like this: "no-http-string": [true, "http://www.example.com/?.*", "http://www.examples.com/?.*"]

(Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/blob/master/README.md)

Therefore, assuming you trust the World Wide Web Consortium, you could give it an exception in your `tslint.json` like

```
"no-http-string": [true, "http://www.w3.org/.*"]
```